# Rails includes with where condition on jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `jsonb` type of field named `metadata` which is a field of the `OrderItem` model.

I would like to get every order containing an order_item with specific metadata. My current code looks like this:

```
Order.includes(:order_items)
     .where('order_items.metadata @> ?', { category: 'regular' })
```

This produces the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "order_items")
```

Comment: you should use `joins` not `includes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `joins` instead of `includes`.